# Image transformation using GDAL

Tags: image, transform, gdal, shift

I have an image in UTM and want to be able to apply a shift in easting and northing using gdal tools. Does any body know which gdal function and how to re-project an image with shifts only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When only shifting is required I would suggest to use **gdalwarp**. The option **-te xmin ymin xmax ymax** is the right choice to specify the shift with coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax? Is there anyway that I just specify the shift values rather than first finding the image extent?

Comment: You can get the values by using 'gdalinfo yourfile.tif' , for example. You will find lots of information about your file. You will also see information about the corner coordinates (like: Upper Left, Lower Left,...). In addition I don't think you can just specify the shift values. Maybe there is a way, but when you just have one image to shift, rather than multiple images, it's more effective to find the extend first and then adding or subtracting the shift from that coordinates. Hope this helps.